# Tailwind grid container slightly changes when cycling through tabs and a tab has vertical scroll in it

Tags: javascript, css, tailwind-css

I have a tabs component contained within a grid container. One of these tabs has a vertical scroll element to contain all the text in that tab area. When I click on this tab with the scroll bar, the vertical height of the grid container increases slightly - I have no clue why. When going to the other tabs (without scroll bars) it is more consistent. How do I prevent this from happening? This is my code:

Component:

```
'use client'
import React from 'react'
import PatientNotesDropDown from '../misc/PatientNotesDropDown'
import { Tabs, Tab } from '../misc/Tabs'

const PatientNotes = () => {
  return (
    
    <div className='h-full text-black flex flex-col justify-between'>
        <div className='flex flex-col min-h-0 flex-grow justify-start rounded-xl border-2 border-zinc-400 backdrop-blur-sm h-full '>
            <div className='flex justify-center px-4 pt-2 pb-2 items-center'>
                <div className='tracking-widest text-lg'>
                    <p>PATIENT NOTES</p>
                </div>

            </div>
            
            <div className='flex-grow min-h-0 px-2 pb-3 grid'>
                <Tabs >
                    <Tab label="MEDICAL">
                        <div className="h-full justify-between px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center border-black border-2'>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">PAST MEDICAL HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            
                            
                        </div>
                    </Tab>

                    <Tab label="SURGICAL">
                        <div className="px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center '>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">PAST SURGICAL HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </Tab>



                    <Tab label="FAMILY">
                        <div className="px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center '>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">FAMILY HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            <div className='h-full overflow-auto'>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">IMMEDIATE FAMILY</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">SECONDARY FAMILY</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">TERTIARY FAMILY</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">CHILDREN</h2>
                                     
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>


                    <Tab label="SOCIAL">
                        <div className="px-8 pt-2">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center '>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">SOCIAL HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            <div className='h-full max-h-full overflow-auto border-2 border-black'>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">HOUSING</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">OCCUPATION</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">FITNESS</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">SMOKING, ALCOHOL AND ILLICIT SUBSTANCES</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                    
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>


                    <Tab label="PHYSC">
                        <div className="flex flex-col h-full justify-start px-8 py-5">
                            <div className='flex justify-between items-center '>
                                <h2 className="text-sm font-base tracking-widest">PSYCHIATRIC HISTORY</h2>
                                <PatientNotesDropDown />
                            </div>
                            <div className='flex-grow overflow-y-auto '>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">MENTAL STATE EXAMINATION</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">PREVIOUS ADMISSIONS</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">FORENSIC HISTORY</h2>
                                     
                                </div>

                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">RISKS</h2>
                                     
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">NOV 3 2009</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">NOV 3 2009</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">NOV 3 2009</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <h2 className="text-sm font-base mb-2 pt-4 tracking-widest border-b-[1px] border-b-black">NOV 3 2009</h2>
                                    <p className='text-xs'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur accumsan ligula et enim aliquam ultrices. Duis risus urna, sodales rutrum erat eget, volutpat commodo ipsum. Fusce ac tortor posuere, tincidunt diam id, congue augue. Sed id dui ac est varius bibendum sit amet eget risus. Ut nunc ex, semper at sodales eget, hendrerit vitae tellus. In id velit mollis, elementum ligula eget, volutpat diam. Duis varius quis lorem nec rhoncus. Fusce aliquet ligula ac facilisis pharetra.</p>
                                </div>
                                
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </Tab>
                </Tabs>
            </div>

            
        
        </div>
        <div>
            <h2 className='text-center tracking-widest font-medium text-xs pt-1'>PATIENT NOTES</h2>
        </div>
    
    </div>
  )
}

export default PatientNotes
```

Tabs:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Tabs = ({ children, width }) => {
  const [activeTab, setActiveTab] = useState(children[0].props.label);

  const handleClick = (e, newActiveTab) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setActiveTab(newActiveTab);
  };

  return (
    <div className="mx-2 place-self-center w-full flex flex-col min-h-0 h-full ">
      <div className="flex justify-between">
        {children.map(child => (
          <button
            key={child.props.label}
            className={`${
              activeTab === child.props.label ? 'border-l-[1px] border-t-[1px] border-r-[1px] rounded-t-lg border-b-[1px] border-b-gray-50 ' : 'border-l-[1px] border-t-[1px] border-r-[1px] rounded-t-lg'
            } text-center text-gray-700 font-base py-1 border-zinc-500 text-[10px]  tracking-widest -mb-[1px] w-full ml-1 mr-1`}
            onClick={e => handleClick(e, child.props.label)}
          >
            {child.props.label}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div className="py-2 border-zinc-500 border-[1px] min-h-0 ml-1 mr-1 rounded-b-lg max-h-full h-full">
        {children.map(child => {
          if (child.props.label === activeTab) {
            return <div key={child.props.label} className='min-h-0 h-full '>{child.props.children}</div>;
          }
          return null;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

const Tab = ({ label, children }) => {
  return (
    <div label={label} className="hidden">
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
export { Tabs, Tab };
```

Parent Grid:

```
<div className="grid grid-cols-12 grid-rows-10 gap-3 p-3 h-screen place-items-stretch ">
      <div className="col-span-12 bg-gray-200">1</div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-5 row-start-2 bg-gray-200 min-h-0"><LastVisitedPatient /></div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-3 col-start-1 row-start-7 bg-gray-200 min-h-0"><Bloods /></div>
      <div className="col-span-12 col-start-1 row-start-10 bg-gray-200">6</div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-2 bg-gray-200">7</div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-2 col-start-10 row-start-4 bg-gray-200">8</div>
      <div className="col-span-3 row-span-4 col-start-10 row-start-6 h-full bg-gray-200">9</div>
      <div className="col-span-6 row-span-8 col-start-4 row-start-2 bg-gray-200 min-h-0"><PatientNotes /></div>
    </div>
```